# Windows 7 - How to whitelist connections on schedule basis?

Tags: windows-7, networking, administrator, blocking

How can I block internet connection to all websites and applications except given websites and application between 09:00 AM to 05:00 PM. After that time, everything should be unblocked.
I want a solution that block connection, not just website. So, no matter which application it is, it's connection should be blocked.

I want this schedule every Monday-Friday. How can I do this?

Comment: Setup suiting firewall rules and a script that applies them/removes them.

Comment: I am not that expert in these things, can you please write detailed answer that I can follow step by step.

Comment: You could use the task scheduler to schedule the execution and [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx) to setup the actual rules. For the rule you would simply setup one that blocks all access and one which whitelists your target. You're likely going to run into issues as currently you'd be blocking DNS as well and many other services that might be necessary.